# Child form always on top of parent

Tags: delphi

I think this is a question that time after time appear here, but I looked over lots of questions, and didn't found the the right answer for me.

I have a parent form, with all "normal" attributes, and now I just created a child form, with "normal" attributes too. On my parent form, I have a ListView, when I click on some item at my ListView, I open the child form.

Now I need to keep this child form, on top of the main form, and when I minimize the child, the top gets minimized too, when I maximize the program, I see the child form only, until I close this form. So, the main form, with the ListView will be unavailable until I close the child form. If I select another item from my ListView, I open the child form again with the same behavior.

I don't know if this is hard to achieve, but I didn't found it over the google. 
Here is my simple demo code:

```
unit Unit1;

var
  Form1: TForm1;


implementation

uses Desktop;

procedure TForm1.RemoteDesktop1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DesktopForm: TForm2;
begin
  DesktopForm:= TForm2.Create(Self);
  DesktopForm.Show;
end;
```

And Desktop unit is just a VCL Form, without any code.

Comment: The real problem is that you are allowing a modal form to be minimized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [showModal](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_ShowModal.html). To minimize MainWindow (all windows, minimize app actually), you should override WMSysCommand in child form:

```
procedure WMSyscommand(var Msg: TWmSysCommand); message WM_SYSCOMMAND;

.
.
.
procedure TForm2.WMSysCommand(var Msg: TWmSysCommand);
begin
  case (Msg.CmdType and $FFF0) of
    SC_MINIMIZE:  begin
                    Msg.Result := 0;
                    EnableWindow(Application.Handle, True);
                    Aplication.Minimize;
                  end;
    else inherited;
  end;
end;
```

Also Form event `WindowStateChange` could be used on non Windows.

I've run simple test without handling that event on LXDE Fedora23 (Lazarus) all forms have been minimize when modal.

Comment: I put the procedure declaration on private at TForm1 (main form), and used ShowModal to display the child form, but when minimized, the main form still open, it doesn't get minimized together...

Comment: It works if I put your procedure on the modal form, not on the main form. I will accept the answer, but consider to add this edit.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a Modal form

```
DesktopForm.ShowModal;
```

instead of

```
DesktopForm.Show;
```

you will probably want to set

Application.ModalPopupModel to pmAuto also

Comment: I tried this right now, but when I minimize the modal form, I still see the main form. I need it to get minimized together.